# KendoUI doesn't load properly in firefox

Tags: kendo-ui

What could be reason that KendoUI loads all templates and shows them fine in chrome, safari, opera but in firefox the container div stays empty, and no errors or warning in the console.

Comment: Unless you share some code showing the symptoms it is hard to say. Try posting some code using JSFiddle or JSBin